# Probability that all $k$ partitions of a set of size $n$ have at least one element

Tags: probability, combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion, set-partition

My question is based on problem 1 in https://projects.iq.harvard.edu/files/stat110/files/strategic_practice_and_homework_2.pdf

Is there a compact solution to the question below?

Given a set of size $n$, what is the probability that all $k$ partitions have at least one element?

Comment: As the title in the problem suggest, use Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion

Comment: @user2661923 that is actually correct but since this is Stat 110 I presume OP is not supposed to use Stirling Numbers

Comment: The denominator should be $k^n$ and no multiplier. From the source question, the question is the probability of the random function $f:[n]\to [k]$ is onto. @user2661923 Specifically for $n=7,k=4.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Well, this is embarrassing.  I have therefore deleted all of my previous comments.

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja Actually I'm just trying to improve my probability skills so it's ok to use any approach. It seems that we can use inclusion exclusion and my question is exactly Stirling numbers of the second kind.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I'm confused. Could you please explain what is the difference between this question and Stirling numbers? I tried to calculate the probability and I get $1/k^n$ instead of $1/k!$ which appears in Stirling numbers.

Comment: Nvm! I got it! The question is different from Stirling number because subsets also have assigned "indices" (e.g. season in this question).